# MySQL resets AUTO_INCREMENT for a table on service restart

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment

I have MySQL (InnoDB) database that resets it's auto increment value when the service is restarted. This causes duplicate primary key inserts, which fail.

This was not happening until recently. It started happening when a colleague accidentally dropped a table from the database. The single table was restored from a backup, but the structure changed a little (integers where replaced with double, vchars got a bit bigger) and the auto increment now resets each time the mysql service is restarted.

The create schema for the table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `caseattachments` (
  `CaseAttachmentId` double NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CaseId` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `CaseEventId` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `OriginalFileName` varchar(768) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OriginalFileMimeType` varchar(768) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OriginalFileSize` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `NewFileName` varchar(768) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CaseAttachmentId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6589 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Why might the auto increment be getting reset each time the service is restarted?

**UPDATE**

The fix for this was fairly trivial (in my case) I dropped the table and rebuilt it to use integers for the Id's. This seems to have fixed the problem. I'm not sure what the fix would have been if I'd had a large table, hopefully I won't need to find out.

Comment: I haven't seen the `DOUBLE` type used with `AUTO_INCREMENT`. I thought it was used only integer types like `INT` (4 bytes), `TINYINT` (1 byte) and `BIGINT` (8 bytes) when one has really big tables.

Comment: @ypercube: Apparently it is legal to use with floating-point values: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html "An integer or floating-point column can have the additional attribute AUTO_INCREMENT. When you insert a value of NULL (recommended) or 0 into an indexed AUTO_INCREMENT column, the column is set to the next sequence value. Typically this is value+1, where value is the largest value for the column currently in the table. AUTO_INCREMENT sequences begin with 1."

Answer (score 1):

Its here:

```
AUTO_INCREMENT=6589
```

Your index has been reset to 6589, and will do duplicates until it reaches the number which is available, either take this out, or make sure its 1+ the last id in the table.

So if the last row had id  98120, yuu need to change it to

AUTO_INCREMENT=98121

Or am I stating the obvious?

if its a current problem and you need to fix a live table do:

```
ALTER TABLE caseattachments AUTO_INCREMENT = 98121
```

Comment: The AUTO_INCREMENT value is larger than the current largest value. What I'm seeing is that after the restart the next value that is inserted is 1, not 6589.

Comment: Do you restart the service with some arguments? Do you have an example of the command used to restart mysql?
Also, what version of MySQL are you using?